# How to read the value of a custom workflow argument in a MSBuild proj file

Tags: msbuild, workflow

I added a custom workflow argument using the steps outlined [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx). Now, how do I read the value of this argument from the custom MSBuild script I have included in the build definition that uses this custom workflow?

**UPDATE:**
There really is no need to add a custom argument to the workflow. Following the steps below I was able to pass an argument to the MSBuild script for a Exec command.

1. In the build definiton under MSBuildArguments, add `/p:CommandArg=dev`
2. In the custom MSBuild script add a new property `<CommandArg>placeholder</CommandArg>`
3. Edit Exec command to be: `<Exec Command=CALL run.cmd $(CommandArg)/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the MSBuild Workflow Activity Parameters to include your new argument.  If you search your XAML workflow for mtbwa:MSBuild you should be able to clearly see how the CommandLine build arguments are being build via a String.Format and add your parameter to the set of arguments passed in.

Comment: I am not sure how this will help me accomplish my goal since I am not looking for actual project build arguments. I need to read the argument value and use it in the custom MSBuild script as an argument to a Exec command. Eg: If the custom argument's (in the workflow) value is say "dev", I need the MSBuild script to pick that up as `<Exec Command="CALL run.cmd dev`/>, if its "test", then as `<Exec Command="CALL run.cmd test`/>

Comment: So if you pass the value into your MSBuild commandline arguments as $(MyCustomValue)=<yourvalue>, where <yourvalue> is the Workflow argument inserted via String.Format, then you can reference $(MyCustomValue) anywhere in your MSBuild script (i.e. <Exec Command="CALL run.cmd $(MyCustomValue)" />)...  In a sense you are relaying the value from Workflow to MSBuild and assigning from one variable context to another.